# Load different template for CPT (in loop) in my plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, templates

I'm writing a plugin that register a new CPT named "sec-feature". In the following loop in my index.php, I want to load a feature-template.php for this CPT posts. But `get_template_part` just locate for the file in theme directory. I want this functionality: if this file doesn't exist in theme directory, locate it on my plugin directory instead.

Is there any way to do this(not by hard coding) or handling output template by the plugin?

```
$args = array( 'post__in' => array(244,302),
'post_type' => array( 'sec-feature')
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  get_template_part('feature-template');    
endwhile;
```

**EDIT**

I use the following code in my plugin, but it works just for single posts. In the loop of posts,it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );

public function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
  if ( get_post_type() == 'sec-feature' ) {
$theme_file = get_stylesheet_directory() .'/feature-template.php';
if ( file_exists($theme_file) ) {
    $template_path = $theme_file;
} else {
    $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'feature-template.php';
}
  }
  return $template_path;
}
```

Comment: Can you not use archive-sec-feature.php?

Comment: Hi Andrew,Thanks for your reply,i think it doesn't matter when you handle this by "template_include" filter. i want that wp,detect automatically template in theme directory,if it doesn't exist,check it in plugin directory. i think archive-sec-feature.php can't handle this individually.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hooks in the load sequence triggered by `get_template_part()` that will help you.

1. [`get_template_part()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L158)
2. [`locate_template`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/template.php#L462)
3. [`load_template`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/template.php#L494)

And `locate_template()` is hard-coded to look at theme files. I hate to write "you can't do that" answers, but I honestly don't see a way to override what file `get_template_part()` loads.